# Google sheets =importxml

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I have been trying to build a google sheet so that I can track my crypto portfolio.
I used `=importxml` to get the live data from [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com)

This is the code, where E28 is the

```
XPATH:=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"; E28)
```

It's working perfectly since I added a button that when I click it, refreshes the prices.

Here is the problem... The data that is pulled from coinmarketcap is displayed in the cells as text, not as numbers, even though it is in fact numbers. So when I try to use the data to make my profit/loss formula it says "Function ADD parameter 1 waits for numbers, but "$40,488.71" is actually text and it can't be forced as the number"

What can I do? is it possible to turn this text into numbers? so I can use the values in my formulas?

Did I make myself clear? Regards from Brazil!!!

Comment: About `where E28 is the XPATH:`, can you provide your current xpath?

Comment: xPATH : //*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=Value(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";"//div[@class='priceValue ']");"$";"");",";"");".";","))
```

as you are in Brazil, you have to remove `$`, remove `,` and change `.` by `,` as decimal separator.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!!!!! S2 it worked....

Comment: To find the xpath, I prefer to read the source code of the web page, and try to find the most accurate.